# Pop-Up window When pressed on JList element-Java

Tags: java, swing, list, popup, mouseevent

I have a small problem with my code, what I want to achieve:

1. When I click on the `JList` item it should pop-up a window giving a message.
2. The pop-up window should specifically refer to that element which I clicked on for example I press on car, it should something like "the vehicle you click on is a car"

The code which I wrote so far:

```
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
  import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
  javax.swing.JList;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

      public class Test extends JFrame {
private JList list;
private static String[] names = { "car ", "bike", "skate" };

public Test() {
    super("title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(650, 800);

    list = new JList(names);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    add(new JScrollPane(list));
    setVisible(true);
    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseisClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "testing");
            }
        }
    };
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String agrs[]) {
    Test t1 = new Test();
}
}
```

Comment: *"I have a small problem with my code"* What's your question?  *"what I want to achieve:"*  No.. that's a specification or requirement.  What is your *question?*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MouseEvent to get the component that generated the event:

```
JList list = (JList)mouseEvent.getSource();
System.out.println(list.getSelectedValue().toString());
```

Edit:

```
public void mouseisClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
```

You are not implementing the proper method. It should be:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
```

Always use the @Override when you override a method to prevent making typing mistakes.

Comment: but it doesn't pop-up anything when i double  click it